# Struts 2: Action result. How show in browser address line link on jsp?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, struts2, action

For example on our `index.jsp` contains only one link:

```
<a href="<s:url action='viewBook'/>">Your Book</a>
```

In browser on `index.jsp` page I see this link:

```
http://localhost:8080/project/viewBook.action
```

when I click on this link opened page and in browser address line I see next address:

```
http://localhost:8080/project/viewBook.action
```

`struts.xml` contains next lines for action listTicket:

```
    <action name="viewBook" class="BookAction" method="view">
        <result>pages/book.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

**My question: what I must change, that instead viewBook.action in browser I see link to the Page:**

```
http://localhost:8080/project/book.jsp
```

I try set for result tag type="redirect". But in this case - page empty.

Comment: I'm wildly guessing you can't do this. Struts is a controller-oriented  framework, not a view-oriented one like JSF. An action (controller) can choose between one of several views to display, so in the general case you can't tell which JSP will be displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't see the backing view file shown in the URL, nor should you want to. View mechanics are an abstraction and not shown in essentially all MVC frameworks.

You'll see `viewBook.action` (assuming default action extension) if you redirect to the action using a [`"redirectAction"` result type](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/redirect-action-result.html). This is the desired URL.

Answer (score 3):

You should not do this.
 You want the url to link to your **controller** and not your jsp.